# Cannot run mysql command even though homebrew lists it as being installed

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I have installed mysql version 5.7 using homebrew. Once completed, I then ran the mysql command and I am told it does not exist.

Observe the following terminal output...

```
user@MacBook-Air ~ % brew install mysql@5.7   
Warning: mysql@5.7 5.7.38 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 5.7.38, run:
  brew reinstall mysql@5.7
user@MacBook-Air ~ % mysql
zsh: command not found: mysql
user@MacBook-Air ~ %
```

How can I run mysql from the command line once install from homebrew?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the mysql bin path is not added in the PATH variable. Try this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/your_mysql_home_path/bin
export PATH
```

Note: That is for the current session, which is reset when you log out(or close the terminal window). You might want to edit your user profile `.bash_profile` in your user's home directory or the global profile `/etc/profile` and change the PATH value to make it persistent.